# Java question :instance of a class as a static member of this class

Tags: java, class, static, member

I am maintaining a Java program , I am not the author.
I came accros the following situation:
In the code below I do not the declaration

```
    static MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
```

What is the purpose of this statement?

See below the whole code

```
public class MainWindow {
static MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();

// constructors
public MainWindow() {       
    System.out.println("this is the constructor.");     
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    System.out.println("this is main method.");

}
```

}

Comment: I suggest you first try to find out what is the purpose of the MainWindow class, then, if you need further assistance,  provide more details about that class.  Technically the static means the "frame" variable is shared among all instances of MainWindow, but not clear from these few lines why.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this was done in order to only ever have one instance of the `MainWindow` across the program, however in that case I would expect the constructor to be private and the static member to be public.